# Display and filter geoJSON type instead of vector type

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

I am using [this example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/filter-features-within-map-view/) directly from Mapbox to filter features within map view, as it is exactly the functionality I am looking for.

However, I have been struggling to replace the .addLayer part with GeoJSON, that I am getting from MongoDB. The dataset I wish to display and filter from MongoDB looks like that:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ba64a3c517f3a78325d1534"),
    "geometry" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            13.3325, 
            52.4564
        ]
    },
    "properties" : {
        "name" : "Roberts",
        "entry" : "Tax Advisor",
        "fromPrice" : 125,
        "unit" : "hour"
    },
    "type" : "Feature",
    "__v" : 0
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ba64a3c517f3a78325d1533"),
    "geometry" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            13.314, 
            52.4901
        ]
    },
    "properties" : {
        "name" : "Taylor",
        "entry" : "Law Firm",
        "fromPrice" : 160,
        "unit" : "hour"
    },
    "type" : "Feature",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Of cause this is not about airports, but the concept is the same. I'd be grateful if someone can help me get the geoJSON into this filter. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I have to wonder why i got downvoted for a totally valid question... see my own solution below

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to geojson to vector.

```
var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(JSON.stringify(geoData),
    { featureProjection: ol.proj.get('EPSG:4326')})
    }),
   style: new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: 5,
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'red',
            width: 2
        }),
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: '#fff'
        })
    })
})
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for this fast answer! I could not make it work however. I found another solution that I posted.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using the code below to replace and adjusting other code from the example to reflect the change in what data is passed.

```js
      map.addSource("entries", {
          "type": "geojson",
          "data": {
              "type": "FeatureCollection",
              "features": database-data-here
          }
      });

      map.addLayer({
          "id": "locations",
          "type": "circle",
          "source": "entries",
          "paint": {
              "circle-radius": 8,
              "circle-color": "#41b9c1"
          },
          "filter": ["==", "$type", "Point"],
      });
```